# Approximate $u$ Lipschitz continuous by smooth convex functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $u: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ be a  Lipschitz continuous function. Can we find a sequence of **smooth convex functions** $u_n$ such that $$u_n \to u$$

1. uniformly;
2. or uniformly on compact sets?

Comment: At this point, in view of Theo Bendit's answer, you can add to your original question another with the added hypothesis that $u$ be convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; the pointwise limit of convex functions will be convex (let alone uniform convergence on any bornology), so any Lipschitz continuous function that isn't convex cannot be approximated by smooth convex functions.

If you insist on $u$ being convex, I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.1042.pdf), which was published in the Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society. It shows that every convex function can be uniformly approximated by analytic convex functions.